# Создание полной копии библиотеки и интерпретатора

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как создать полную локальную копию библиотеки python и его интерпретатора в отдельную локальную папку?

Comment: Посмотрите: `shutil.copytree`

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать виртуальное окружение с помошью сторонней утилиты virtualenv. См подробней virtualenv.

Comment: virtualenv не создаёт полную копию